# Visual Studio error: The program '[5308] myNewOpenCV.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8&feature=iv&src_vid=bSeFrPrqZ2A&annotation_id=annotation_178711) tutorial and tried to run the following code:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main() {

    //Create matric to store image
    Mat image;
    //initialize capture

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    //create window to show image
    namedWindow("window", 1);

    while (1){

        // copy webcam stream to image
        cap >> image;

        // print image to screen
        imshow("window", image);

        //delay 33ms
        waitKey(33);

    }
}
```

However I got the following errors:

```
'myNewOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Or\Copy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\myNewOpenCV\Debug\myNewOpenCV.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'myNewOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'myNewOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'myNewOpenCV.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[5308] myNewOpenCV.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

and the program does not run. I've tried to re install the opevCV libraries like suggested on some places but it didn't work.
I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 REL and Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried to check whether `VideoCapture` is opened properly? Furthermore, mixing of debug/release dll's can cause such a thing.

Comment: Thank you for our reply, How can I check that?

Comment: [VideoCapture::isOpened](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-isopened), and take care for debug dll's have `d` suffix, e.g. `opencv_core###d.dll`

Comment: The problem was the way I defined my PATH (I did 64-bit instead of 32-bit. My Visual studio is 32 probably...). Now I have a new problem: MSVCP100.dll Missing Error. I'll try to solve it too...

Comment: MSVCP100.dll, is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 runtime libraries, so ensure you are using the VC12 version of OpenCV's dll's

Comment: Thank you, problem solved! However, it only works for me with an external usb camera and not with the built in one. I get this error: `First-chance exception at 0x7702C42D in myNewOpenCV.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0028FAA8.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`